# jQuery Datatables work Locally but not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, heroku, datatables

I am working on implementing jquery-datatables-rails gem into my application. I can initiate it successfully on my local host, but when I push to Heroku, my table that is supposed to convert to a DataTable does and shows nothing.

I have followed many tutorials but for some reason can not get it to initiate. Here is my setup:

**Application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-dropdown
//= require bootstrap
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

**Application.css**

```
 *= require_self
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
 *= require_tree .
```

**Locations.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
    $('#locations').dataTable
      sPaginationType: "bootstrap"
      sDom: "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>"
```

And my **application.rb** does contain: config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

**After More Testing**

After much testing, it seems like Data Tables is not taking a liking to some of my fields. It is very strange. For example:

```
<td><%= network.name %></td>
<td><%= network.user.try(:name) %></td>
<td><%= network.phone_number %></td>
<td><%= network.user.try(:email) %></td>
```

If I remove the :email and :user field, DT works. I thought maybe it was because the way it was formatted so I even tried to convert it to the same layout as <%= network.name %> and still does not work. The second I remove it, it works again.

Very Strange

Comment: Also gem 'jquery-datatables-rails' is OUTSIDE the :assets group

Comment: are there any errors that are being dumped to console? maybe provide a log trace from your heroku app?

Comment: Just checked the Heroku Logs and nothing is popping up in the form of errors. It is like Heroku does not even the see the call to make it a data table. Weird why my Local Host works perfect though

Comment: Do you get any Javascript errors?

Comment: did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: @sixty4bit - I have gained extensive knowledge in DT since this post. If you have a question, feel free to ping me. I would be glad to help if I can.

Comment: thanks @RubyNewbie. sorry for my ignorance but how do I ping you?

Comment: @RubyNewbie I'm having the same problem with a Flask app and posted on Heroku, locally it works but not on Heroku. Do you know how to solve it? Repository: https://github.com/guimatheus92/Game-Recommendation-System